# No bean named 'cxf' is defined even after importing cxf.xml

Tags: apache, rest, cxf

I tried to expose one of my method as REST webservice using Apache CXF. When I try to access the webservice at **http://localhost:7080/CXFwithMaven/services/book/abc** i get the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:694)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:75)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried searching on the internet and found that this usually happens when you don't import cxf files such as

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

Although i have imported the files, i am still getting the same error.

Please see the below **VO**.
package sample.cxfwithspring;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Book")
public class BookVO {
    private String name;
    private String author;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

And here is my **service**.

```
package sample.cxfwithspring;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/book")
public interface BookService {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Path("/{name}")
    public BookVO getBook(@PathParam("{name}") String name);

}
```

And **serviceImpl**

```
package sample.cxfwithspring;

public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    public BookVO getBook(String name) {
        BookVO bookVO = new BookVO();
        bookVO.setAuthor("abc");
        bookVO.setName("Rest with CXF");
        return bookVO;
    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:cxf.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and **cxf.xml**

```
<beans xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
 http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <jaxrs:server address="/" id="connectionService">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="book" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml">
            </entry>
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean class="sample.cxfwithspring.BookServiceImpl" id="book">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>CXFwithMaven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CXFwithMaven Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.fastinfoset</groupId>
            <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>CXFwithMaven</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please help me out as I am a newbie to Apche CXF and tried searching everywhere but wasn't able to find a solution for this.

Comment: Look at the section that says "Declaring your server beans" http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html  I guess you want a spring managed bean here

Comment: That article is for SOAP webservice, I am trying to write a REST webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, adding these two lines was the problem

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

Removing them did the trick.
**:D**